# How to fix this? RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When I added an item to dictionary with `in a` function, it's giving this error:

```
inv = { "rope": 1, "torch": 6, "gold coin": 42, "dagger": 1, "arrow": 12 }
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
def AddInventory(invloop, lst):
  for item in lst:
    for k,v in invloop.items():
      if item == k:
        v += 1
      else:
        invloop[item] = 1
  return(invloop)
inv = AddInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you should not add items to the inventory while looping over it. What's more, you don't need that inner loop, because the advantage of a dictionary is that you have direct access via the keys: you can test whether it has a key or not with the `in` operator.

So do this instead:

```
def AddInventory(invloop, lst):
    for item in lst:
        if item in invloop:
            invloop[item] += 1
        else:
            invloop[item] = 1
    return(invloop)
```